# ExtJS4 - ComboBox event for selecting an item

Tags: javascript, combobox, extjs4

I need to find the correct event that is fired *every time* an item is selected in a single-selection type of `ComboBox`.

The documentation can be a little bit unclear about this. Here's a link for reference:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox

I tried [`select`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-event-select) and [`change`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Field-event-change), with the following results:

- `select` is fired just once, when I select an item for the first
  time, and it's not fired ever again when selecting other items;
- `change` does not fire at all.

ExtJS version used is 4.2.0.

**Edit:** It seems that `select` works when selecting with the keyboard, but selecting with mouse have the effect described above. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the JSON populating the `ComboBox` wasn't providing the property set to be the `id` of the `ComboBox` item.

Simply providing it solved the problem and the event `select` now works fine.